# Routing Configuration In Redhat Linux To Communicate Two Different Network

Tags: rhel, ip, route, forwarding

I have created three RedHat virtual machines named: **server**, **client1**, **client2** in VirtualBox manager. **server** is connected to **client1** on network `10.1.1.x` with NIC card (internal network = inet1) and **server** is also connected with **client2** on network `10.2.2.x` with another NIC card (internal network = inet2).

I want to communicate from `10.1.1.x` network to `10.2.2.x`. However, I did route configuration in **client1** and **client2** to communicate with **server** and both machines (**client1**, **client2**) are able to communicate with server and vice versa. I also enabled the IP forwarding in my server machine but I'm not able to communicate between **client1** and **client2**.

**Below are IP configurations of my three machines**

**server**: /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s8

```
static
ip add 10.1.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 10.1.1.0
broadcast 10.1.1.255
```

**server**: /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s9

```
static
ip add 10.2.2.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 10.2.2.0
broadcast 10.2.2.255
```

**client1**: /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp08

```
static
ip add 10.1.1.10
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 10.1.1.0
broadcast 10.1.1.255
```

**client2**: /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp08

```
ip add 10.2.2.10
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 10.2.2.0
broadcast 10.2.2.255
```

**Route configurations**

**client1**:

```
route add -net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 gw 10.1.1.1 dev enp0s8
```

**client2**:

```
route add -net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 gw 10.2.2.1 dev enp0s8
```

Note: Firewall services are also disabled

That is all I have configured, please suggest me what can I do to communicate between `10.1.1.x` and `10.2.2.x`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try ( am not sure though ):

**client 1:** route add -net 10.2.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.1.1.1 dev enp0s8

**client 2:** route add -net 10.1.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.2.2.1 dev enp0s8

Comment: I only did
client1
route add -net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 gw 10.1.1.1 dev enp0s8 
client2
route add -net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 gw 10.2.2.1 dev enp0s8

Comment: can you tell that why the above mentioned route config not work where i have given the 10.0.0.0 whole network to route

Comment: Thanks and Welcome !!!   You mentioned the network and netmask wrongly thats it i guess..All other are fine...10.0.0.0 is not the network ,each network is different as mentioned in the configuration...